# Problema consultando un array anidado y mostrándolo en HTML en Angular

Tags: json, angular, rest

Intento mostrar los resultados específicos de un Array multidimensional recibido por REST pero me devuelve un error cuando intento mostrarlo en HTML.

Recibo un JSON del tipo:

```json
{
    "results": [{
        "state": 0,
        "status": [{
            "name": "player",
            "columns": [
                "time",
                "host",
                "usage_guest"
            ],
            "values": [
                [
                    "2020-08-17T08:09:00Z",
                    "cputotal",
                    "oc33775.host.com"
                ],
                [
                    "2020-08-17T08:09:00Z",
                    "cpukop",
                    "o4665.host.com"
                ]
            ]
        }]
    }]
}
```

En mi componente llamo al servicio así:

```
listaCBS_CPU = [];
this.cbsServicio.getListadoCBS()
.subscribe( ( respuesta:any ) => {
  this.listaCBS=respuesta;
  console.log(this.listaCBS);
  });
}
```

El servicio me retorna:

```
 getListadoCBS(){
   return this.httpClient.get(`${this.PHP_API_SERVER}`,{ responseType: 'text' });
 }
```

Por consola me muestra correctamente el resultado de la consulta. Sin embargo cuando intento mostrar el array en el HTML me da el error **"Only arrays and iterables are allowed"**

```
 <div *ngFor="let cbs of listaCBS">{{cbs.host}}</div>
```

Cómo debería sacar los datos? con algún pipe? con ngFor anidados?

ACTUALIZACIÓN!

he conseguido mostrar los datos de esta forma:

```
  <span *ngFor="let cbs of listaCBS.results">
      <span *ngFor="let cbseries of cbs.series">
      <table> 
       <tr *ngFor="let cbsvalues of cbseries.values">
           <td>{{cbsvalues}}</td>
       </tr>  
      </table>
      </span>   
  </span>
```

Declarando listaCBS así:

```
  listaCBS: listaCBSCPU = new listaCBSCPU();//listaCBSCPU creado como model
```

Sin embargo no logro mostrar los campos de manera independiente. Cuando quiero mostrar:

```
    {{cbsvalues.usage_guest}}
```

no me muestra nada. Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Si no generas alguna modificación a tu respuesta, el problema es al hacer el ngfor, por que no es un array, es un objeto, intenta con ```*ngFor="let cbs of listaCBS.results"```

Comment: @EduardoJaramilloLicea me devuelve el error "Property 'results' does not exist on type 'any[]'.".

Comment: que deseas imprimir de tu objeto json??

Comment: y de esta forma? ´*ngFor="let cbs of listaCBS?.results"´

Comment: por favor que version de angular estas usando es muy importante eso.

Comment: @DavElsanto la 9

Comment: @JackNavaRow me dice que results no está dentro de any

Comment: agregale al final un async

Comment: por favor muestra como declaras la variable **this.listaCBS**

Comment: @DavElsantoestá justo encima de la suscripción, la declaro así listaCBS_CPU = [];

Comment: He hecho una actualización de la pregunta.

Comment: pero si recibes un json porque añades el `responseType: 'text'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He resuelto mostrar los campos:

```
 <span *ngFor="let cbs of listaCBS.results">
    <span *ngFor="let cbseries of cbs.series">
     <table> 
      <tr *ngFor="let cbsvalues of cbseries.values">
        <td>{{cbsvalues[0}}</td>
        <td>{{cbsvalues[1}}</td>
        <td>{{cbsvalues[2}}</td>
      </tr>  
     </table>
     </span>   
 </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

suponiendo que lo que quieres formar es una tabla donde las columnas vienen dadas por tu propiedad **columns** y vas a iterar los valores de **values** puedes realizar lo siguiente:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let auxColumn of listaCBS.results[0].status[0].columns">{{auxColumn}}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let aux of listaCBS.results[0].status[0].values">
    <th *ngFor="let auxData of aux">{{auxData}}</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Correcto, ese es el punto. Sin embargo, me sigue diciendo que results no está en "any", debería declararlo como un objeto?

Comment: El problema principal es tu JSON. Tiene la estructura correcta sí pero es muy difícil de entender pues los atributos los estas manejando como array no sé si es la forma en la pretenden manejar toda la información.

Comment: La estrucutra viene dada de una base de datos InfluxDB, de su API particular, es difícil de modificar ese dato, para ello debería usar PHP (en mi caso) para reconfigurar el JSON

Comment: No del todo. Lo que intento saber es si **results** siempre va a ser un vector con un único valor.

Comment: sí, siempre llegará esa misma estructura.